# Analog div for using in C# (server)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

What is analog in C#?

js:

```
$('#MyDiv').show();
var d = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
d.innerHTML = someLargeHtmlCode;
```

html:

```
<div id="MyDiv" runat="server" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Can I use ? 
Some like that:

html:

```
 <asp:Panel id="MyDiv" runat="server"  style="display: none;">

 </asp:Panel>
```

But I don't know what C# code must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:Panel id="MyDiv" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Literal ID="literal" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

and in your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDiv.Visible = true;
    literal.Text = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: Can I use it in JS and C#? I want change text of literal in JS and C#